# Ubuntu : Turn on and login into a remote computer

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I want to run some application on a remote computer. I am able to turn it on using `wakeonlan` but how can I log into it and start the application using terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh yourusername@computernameorip

ProgramNameToExecute
```